# A very basic question about unconstrained quadratic program

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

In an unconstrained quadratic program given below $$\min.~~ \frac{1}{2}x^TAx+b^Tx$$ why the optimal value is $-\infty$ if $b$ is not in $R(A)$?

Comment: According to stationarity condition, the gradient of the cost function is set to zero yielding $Ax = -b$. The solution would exist when $b$ is in the range of $A$, otherwise the optimal value would be $-\infty$, makes sense?

Comment: @user550103 Thanks for your comment. But, I think if there is no feasible point then the optimal value of a minimization problem is $+ \infty$ and not $- \infty$. Since if there is no $Ax=-b$, the solution does not exist so we should have optimal value $+ \infty$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @user550103 Ok, please comment if my following reasoning is wrong. If $b$ is not in the range of $A$ then we can represent $b$ as the sum of $A$ and some other matrix $B$ such that $b$ is in the range of $A+B$. In this case, even though the part which comprise of $x^TAx+Ax$ may be finite even after performing minimization but we can make $Bx$ approach $-\infty$. Is it right reasoning? (This is a bit abstract but is the concept right?)

Comment: @user550103 I just want to understand how $-\infty$ will be approached?

Comment: @user550103 here is little more formal way for my second comment. We say $b=c+c'$ where $c$ is in range of $A$ while $c'$ is not in range of $A$. Then in this case $c$ and $c'$ are orthogonal. So we can put all the elements of $x$ equal to zero which are corresponding to the non-zero entries of $c$ while we can make the remaining entries of $x$ go to $\pm$ infinity to have an overall answer of $-\infty$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo where did I mention convex in my question? I tagged convex optimization only because $b$ should be in range of $A$ even if its a convex optimization problem. I do not understand your comment.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for your clarification. I will try my best to not do such a mistake again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $b\notin R(A)$. It is well-known that we can decompose ${\mathbf R}^n$ as
$$
       {\mathbf R}^n = N(A^T)\oplus R(A).
$$
(It is easy to see that $N(A^T)\subseteq R(A)^\perp$ and both spaces have the same dimension.)

In particular, we can decompose
$$
       b = z + Ac,
$$
with $A^Tz=0$. Since $b\notin R(A)$, it must be $z\ne0$.

Now take $\lambda\in\mathbf R$. For $x=\lambda z$ we have
\begin{align*}
     \frac{1}{2}x^TAx + b^Tx &= \frac{\lambda^2}{2}z^TAz + \lambda b^Tz\\
                  &= \lambda b^Tz   &&;z^TA=0\\
                  &= \lambda z^Tz + \lambda c^TA^Tz &&;b = z + Ac\\
                  &= \lambda z^Tz &&;A^Tz=0,
\end{align*}
which shows that the quadratic form has no upper or lower bound.